# How to create regional landing pages?

Tags: seo, google, local-seo, google-translate

How can I have different landing pages for different region - different language, image, and other widgets too?

For an example, I want to use:

1. Region A: Display language of region A, Images related to region A, reviews related to region A
2. I want to do similarly for Region B, C, D, and all the major customer regions.

Is it possible to do it via google translate OR I will have to do this manually by creating multiple URLs? What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to do it via google translate OR I will have to do this
> manually by creating multiple URLs?

If you want landing pages that can rank in Google, you will need to **create a separate URL for each**.

Google Translate is a tool for translating text content. It has nothing to do with URLs or how Google crawls, indexes, and ranks your website.

You can use Google Translate to translate content from English to Spanish. However, Google Translate only translates content - it does not localize. It does not know that when translating recipes with ingredients in cups, that some countries prefer ml and others mg. An English text for the US, UK, Australia, and India should use slightly different wording. Same for a German text in Germany and Austria. Therefore, **a native speaker should always edit the text** before it goes online.

If you have multiple countries with the same language, make sure to look into **hreflang**. It is a meta tag to tell Google that you have the same content in multiple languages and/or for multiple countries. That way, you can make sure that English content for the US and English content for the UK are no treated as duplicate content and that both content pieces rank in the appropriate country.

You can find some details here: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/localized-versions